# How to align the pandas series in ipython notebook?

Tags: css, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm using ipython notebook (3.1.0, Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.2.0 (32-bit)) on firefox for python learning.

One annoying thing is that when I print `pandas.series` or `pandas.dataframe.info`, the result in the IPython notebook can't aligned well. as the image "poor" shows. But when I copy the result to the txt editor, it seems to aligned well. So how can I adjust these align in ipython notebook?

Is this something about the custom css of the ipython notebook? Or something about pandas?
sorry I can't post images the poor alignment in my ipython notebook seems like:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 891 entries, 0 to 890
Data columns (total 12 columns):
passengerid    891 non-null int64
survived      891 non-null int64
pclass       891 non-null int64
sex       891 non-null object
age        891 non-null float64
sibsp       891 non-null int64
parch        891 non-null int64
fare          891 non-null float64
embarked      889 non-null object
full name     891 non-null object
salutation    891 non-null object
age_group      891 non-null category
dtypes: category(1), float64(2), int64(5), object(4)
```

update:
poor alignment of df.info :https://www.dropbox.com/s/4aec81dlrwppbwv/df_info.png?dl=0

poor alignment of pandas.series :https://www.dropbox.com/s/2povchsip1mbd31/movielist.png?dl=0

Comment: can you post/edit to add the code that did that ?

Comment: It's simply a pandas.read_csv() to a df,and then type df.info() in the cell of the notebook.

Comment: Did you change something something with custom css yourself? Can you try to post an image somewhere else and post a link?

Comment: No, I've done nothing about the custom css, and I setup anaconda as all default. I will update my question with picture links

Comment: I've never seen your alignment issues, could you try connecting to ipython in chrome

Comment: The font type is not a fixed width type (which is typically used for code), causing the visual misalignment. That means you should have in some way changed the font used in the notebook.

Comment: And please post a simple example, or make it copy/past-able + give where you got the data if you want us to try to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks guys!Your comments really help!
I've tried to install chrome in my laptop and the alignment problem disappear!!
This may be the vision of the firefox.
Next I'll try to update the firefox.
Thanks all!!

Comment: Update:I've changed the fonts type of my firefox for  fixed width type to DejaVu Sans Mono, and everything goes well !!!